# Limit controllers to specific area only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have one Area and in AreaRegistration I defined namespace all controllers in area belongs to.

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller="Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "MySite.Admin.Controllers" }             // Namespaces
            );
```

How to prevent controller in that area to be called even when not that route is matched.
I.E. /home/index (without "admin" word at the beginning).

**EXAMPLE:**

If a have controller "MySite.Admin.Controllers.HomeController" which belongs to area root defined above. I want to forbid controller factory to search for that controller (i.e. throw exception) if it doesn't match route "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}" ("Admin" at the end). 
So if I type "home/index" (no "Admin" at the beginning) web site will throw an error that it can't find controller.

Hope i was clear enough.

Comment: Sorry couldn't understand your question, could you provide an example ?

Answer (score 2):

Add a constraint to match the area!

[Here](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-24-cs.aspx) is a nice read on route constraints.

If you want to write your own custom route constraint, then give the following a read

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2009/01/11/asp-net-mvc-route-constraints.aspx

**Edit:**

Remove the default route and make sure everything is scoped to areas, then home/index will throw an exception as it is not scoped to an area.

Comment: This will enable me to detect the best matched route but will not FORBID controller factory to find controller under specific area

Comment: I believe this removal of default routes will solve the problem but just wondering if this is a good practice?

Comment: This is definitely not a bad practice as you are not hacking any thing out of the framework, you are just configuring your routes for your needs, that's it! :)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. The default route matched and used the controller inside the area because the controller search logic. This is not the most clean behavior in the framework but reasonable.